# Use string matching or boolean flags for performance optimization

Tags: java, performance, optimization, string-comparison

I have a function which checks the validity of several parameters and returns a string with the error messages. In the calling function what i am doing is that checking whether the returned string is empty using `errorString.equals("")` method. If it is not empty, error message is shown. I have heard that string comparison is costly in Java. One other approach i can use is that the error checking function to return a boolean value instead of the string and make the `errorString` a global string and the calling function checks the boolean value returned and display the `errorString` if needed. How much performance improvement i can expect from making this change? Assume that my function will get invoked 1000 times a minute.

**EDIT:-**
eg:-

```
    public void callingFunction(){
    /*
    some operations....
     */
    String errors=checkErrors(param1,param1,param3,param4,param5);
    if(!"".equals(errors)){
        System.out.println(errors);
    }
}
public String checkErrors(String param1,String pram2,String param3,String pram4,String param5){
    String errors="";
    if(param1 == null)
        errors +="param1 is null";
    if(param1.equals(""))
        errors +="param1 is empty";
    /*
    A lot more validity checks...
     */
    return errors;
}
```

Comment: "1000/minute" is *very slow* for a modern CPU. In any case, the *first place* to look when optimizing is a [*performance profile*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)). Since all methods discussed have the *same performance bounds*, then the "performance" Just Doesn't Matter (TM) - and if, for some odd chance, it does matter you'll be able to tell with a performance profile (see above).

Comment: "The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet." — Michael A. Jackson

Comment: I have balanced two slippery fish on each shoulder.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, i will use Java :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment, there is *no* performance issue unless there is a [*benchmark/performance profile*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) that indicates that there is an issue. Practically speaking, in most application-level code, unless the *performance bounds* change, most code is "fast enough" - write code cleanly, and follow the 97/3<sup>1</sup> rule.

> In the calling function what i am doing is that checking whether the returned string is empty using errorString.equals("") method. If it is not empty, error message is shown. I have heard that string comparison is costly in JAVA.

Well, no. `String.equals` is not needlessly "costly" in general, and is definitely not in this particular case. `String.equals` is O(n) for two arbitrary strings of the *same* length, but O(1) for strings of different lengths.

The first thing (well, the second, after checking for null) that `String.equals` does is it compares the lengths of the two strings, and the length is stored in a simple integer variable. If the lengths are not equals, the strings can be immediately determined to be not-equal: the only string with a length of 0 is an empty string.

That is, aside from a few extra instructions (the JIT will likely inline the method call anyway), it will have equivalent performance characteristics of checking a boolean variable.

Also, don't forget that modern CPUs are *very fast*. My CPU, which is "old" operates at 2.2 *billion* Hz; 1000 operations/minute is a mere 16 Hz.

---

<sup>1</sup> 97/3 rule ([courtesy of D. Knuth](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80109)):

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs .. We should *forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time* .. Yet we *should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%*. A good programmer will [..] be wise to *look carefully at the critical code; but only after that code has been identified* ..

Comment: You're soo lucky, all I got is an old 286.

Comment: @user2310289 Then I'd recommend not-Java :(

Comment: So in my case, the only situation where the strings are of equal length is that both are empty strings which will be of complexity O(0) and in all other cases the complexity will be O(1). So is there any modification needed for performance improvement? The 1000 invocations i mentioned is arbitrary, it may increase.

Comment: @ManuViswam O(1), as there is no O(0) - again, this will be the [same complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) (with a small, but slightly large C) than as with checking a discrete/flag boolean variable. I *doubt* that you'll see any noticeable improvement with switching to a separate field (although a benchmark to the contrary *would* prove me wrong!), so just write the code as simply/cleanly as it allows. A separate variable/flag very might be cleaner and, if such applies, choose it for *clarity* and *correctness* - not "performance".

Comment: O(0) was just a mistake. What i understood is that all of my checking will be of complexity O(1) because i am comparing with an empty string. So it wont make much difference if i use a seperate boolean variable.

Comment: @ManuViswam It'll be the same complexity. As libik pointed out, there are equivalent methods to check for an empty string - use the one that is most clear. On neat "trick" is to do `"".equals(foo)`, which will also be false when `foo` is null, but not otherwise throw an Exception. This may or may not be useful here.

Comment: That one is a useful trick, but in my case it is checking null previously. But i will change it this way because it is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you're doing it compeltely wrong.

- if there is only one condition to check, return a `boolean`. Otherwise:
- return a flag word whose various bits indicate the various possible errors if they are set, if you don't need to provide any information other than the failures themselves
- otherwise you should be throwing various kinds of exception.

Comment: There are several conditions to check. Each condition will add different error messages, and any combination of these messages is possible. Throwing different exceptions is also not possible because i have to show all the errors in single message.

Comment: @ManuVisam Your reasoning is specious. You can certainly still show all the errors in a single message and still throw different exceptions. All you have to do is accumulate them at the caller. Or else just construct the return string in a form that is already ready to be displayed and eliminate the entire problem, but it's not a very realistic solution. Or problem.

Comment: What i know about exceptions is (correct me if i am wrong) that only one exception is handled at a time. Even if i catch different exception in the same catch block with | operator, only one will be active at a time right? Please provide me some links so that i can understand about simultaneous handling of multiple exceptions.